# Java data storage in CSV

Tags: java, csv

I tried to writting my user input in java to csv file but i dont know how to my username and password in a cell ,whenever i run my program my new username and new password gets overlapped in the same cell with my old username and old password.

```
    package data1;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


 
public class Data1 {
    
    
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String name ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine ();
        System.out.println("Your Name is "+name  );
        
        
        
        
        
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Data.csv";
        
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
            
            String username = name;
            String password = "123";
            
            
           
                
            sb.append(username);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append (password);
            
            
            pw.print(sb.toString());
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Report saved");
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character. And never catch Exception without handle it. Atleast log them.

Comment: Can you show the output you get and the output you expect please

Comment: This is my output 

run:
Enter your name: 
sam
Your Name is sam
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

and im getting this in excel file

first output
sam 123

2nd output
sam sam123 sam

Comment: Please add the information formatted to your question using the edit button

Comment: what if i have 100 users , signing up wouldnt be hard for me to type in one by one . I would like to know how to use loop for this kind of scenario

Comment: A loop that enters the user automatically?

Comment: BTW: You should first solve your problem befor ou do the next step

Comment: catch(throw new RuntimeException E) ? But im having indentation problem

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead so that all details are in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a good start. The issue I'm seeing is you're outputting the username and password so it looks like this:

```
username,password
```

However, next time it runs, you once again print the username and password without prepending a comma:

```
username,passwordusername2,password2
                 ^ note there is no comma
```

You might try checking if there is already text in the CSV file and adding a comma before the new username and password if there is:

```
username,password,username2,password2
```

Comment: what if i have  100 users , signing up wouldnt be hard for me to type in one by one . I would like to know how to use loop for this kind of scenario

Comment: @SathKanth That's a different question. You'd probably do the same as you're doing now for the first username and password (assuming the file is empty. Otherwise you'd do the check like I've already mentioned). Inside the for loop you would output to the file `,username,password` starting with the second username and password. Note the prepended comma.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities here:

1. Change new FileWriter(filepath,false);
2. Don't silently throw away any possible exception.   If your code is crashing you won't even know it.  Try adding "throw new RuntimeException(E);"  to the exception body.